# how to add pagination in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Can anyone help..

I have this in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*):(.*)$ /cat.php?s=$1 [L]
```

example:  site.com/id:category-name
the code basically works

I have this for pagination

```
RewriteRule ^(.*):(.*)&page=(.*)$ /cat.php?s=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

example:  site.com/id:category-name&page=

i want to use this code for the pagination but it doesn't work
when it is `RewriteRule ^(.*)&page=(.*)$ /cat.php?s=$1&page=$2 [L]`
example: site.com/id&page=1
works without problem

but I want it to be  site.com/id:categoryname&page=
why does the code not work?

How can it be this way?
Example:  site.com/id:category-name&page=

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in .htaccess, you can't capture query parameters (?key=value) directly in a RewriteRule. Instead, you should use RewriteCond to check the query string.

Here's a solution to achieve what you want:

```
# For category with pagination
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^([^:]+):([^/]+)$ /cat.php?s=$1&page=%1 [END]

# For category without pagination
RewriteRule ^([^:]+):([^/]+)$ /cat.php?s=$1 [END]
```

Keep in mind that this will work for apache v.2.4. use `[L]` instead of `[END]` on the previous versions (since END is not available) and also you'd need to make sure subsequent rules don't interfere.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Basically correct, but I'd say you should to turn this around. So that the more specialized rule gets executed first. Otherwise you have _both_ rules getting executed, the first for nothing. Also I would recommend to either use the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag, or, if other rules should come into play as well, add another condition to these rules that prevent the application of the rules when the request has already been rewritten to `/cat.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where my mistake was :) in the file itself(cat.php) I had forgotten to add to the request to verify the page `"OR name='$categoryname'"`

I fixed it (htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*):(.*)$ /cat.php?s=$1&n=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*):(.*)?page=(.*)$ /cat.php?s=$1&n=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Example: site.com/id:categoryname&page=2

And now it works :) Thanks for the help though!